# How to check if duplicate data is present in the database using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show a message saying that the `JourneyID` already exists in the database.

The model is :

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Project_Final.Models
{
using System;

public partial class sp_FMS_Group6_Module3_ViewBonusMilesRequesttt_Result
{
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Remote("Check", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Bonus Miles Request has already been sent!")]
    public Nullable<int> JourneyID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RequestDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
}
```

The following are the actions in my controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Create)
{        
        FMS_Group6_Module3_BonusMilesRequestt objProd = new FMS_Group6_Module3_BonusMilesRequestt();
        objProd.CustomerID = int.Parse(Request.Form["CustomerID"].ToString());
        objProd.JourneyID = int.Parse(Request.Form["JourneyID"].ToString());
        objProd.RequestDate = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form["RequestDate"].ToString());
        objProd.Status = "Pending";

        objDB.FMS_Group6_Module3_BonusMilesRequestt.Add(objProd);

        int i = objDB.SaveChanges();
        if (i > 0)
            ViewBag.Message = "Product details saved successfully";
        return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Your Bonus Miles Request has been successfully sent!');window.location='/Home/GetID'</script>");
        //return Redirect("GetID");
}

public ActionResult Check(string Crreate)
{
        FMS_Group6_Module3_BonusMilesRequestt objProd = new FMS_Group6_Module3_BonusMilesRequestt();
        bool ifJourneyIDExist = false;
        try

        {

            ifJourneyIDExist = Crreate.Equals(objProd.JourneyID) ? true : false;

            return Json(!ifJourneyIDExist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
}
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Make the JournyID "unique" in the DB and handle the error returned by it?

Comment: "MVC" isn't a database technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you insert, you can check in the DB, if the `JourneyID` is exists.

```
if (objDB.FMS_Group6_Module3_BonusMilesRequestt.Any(x => x.JourneyID == objProd.JourneyID))
{
    // Exists
}
```

Comment: So it doesn't exist ... who guarantees it still does not exist when the insert is requested?

Comment: I think, a unique constraint in the DB, as you suggested. That could work without this, but with this, you can check first, and send a helpful message without analysing the EF exception.

Comment: Ah, like a "double safety" , so if it is already taken, you won't try in the first place. OK.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ query to make sure all values (ex enumerable) are not duplicated

```
var noDuplicationVariable = enumerableValues.GroupBy(a => a.Key).All(b => b.Count() == 1);
```

use it as an assertion condition before your function